# Google Play Store deep linking is not working on Android 5.0

Tags: android, google-play, android-5.0-lollipop

I have application published in Google play closed beta program and I'm trying to show popup to user everytime new version is available.

I used [this](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html) as reference and it's working fine on android version 4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4 and 6.0 . But it's not working on android version 5.0 , well technically it works it opens google play store but it shows **item not found** (and on some devices there is no connection) message.

Below is the chunk of code which I'm using to open google play store :

```
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID));
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

## UPDATE:

Android 5.1 is working too. 
Also I used this :

```
marketIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://market.android.com/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID));
```

Which you can find in android licensing example.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than depend on the auto-generated `BuildConfig` class, use the app context specific call: `Context.getPackageName()`.  This should give you the correct value.

Comment: Check your Play console listing: did you accidentally exclude or remove 5.0 or 5.0 supported devices?  What happens if you hard-code the package name rather than rely on the runtime or build time classes?

Comment: I tested all of it and all my beta testers are using 5.0 version.Also it works if you open it with browser I think I found a solution and that documentation link which I referenced is outdated I'll post answer as soon as I test new approach I found.Cheers